# Hyper-V Client Network Dropouts

Tags: hyper-v, network-monitoring

Bit of a strange one I'm having that I can't work out.

The setup: Asus P8Z77-M Pro motherboard, 16GB RAM, Intel i7-3770 CPU, OCZ SSD, NVIDIA Quadro 2000 grpahics card (with RemoteFX on the client); running Windows Server 2012 Standard on bare metal with Hyper-V. One Windows Server 2012 Standard Domain Controller, one Windows 8 Enterprise client with 4GB of RAM allocated, and 1 virtual CPU.

Everything is running pretty well on the test client, except that every 1-5 minutes there is a network dropout on the local ethernet interface (on the client) that stops all connectivity. Typing catches up after this dropout is over.

[image: Network Dropout on right hand side]

Is this the network interface on the motherboard having a heart attack? Or am I doing something wrong? When testing flash videos on the client, the dropouts are more regular - even when playing local videos.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention - this is on the LAN on a gigabite switch.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just can't take this question seriously if you insist on running a Server OS on workstation class hardware.

Comment: local videos wouldn't have anything to do with the nic unless they are on one of the other VMs, but it looks like you might be having one of those issues that pops up when you try to run servers on desktop hardware.  Truthfully, its likely the NIC driver on the Host OS.  It could also be that you have contention issues with CPU/RAM/HD/....  and those are causing your VMs to lock up..  if you run a constant ping, does it fail during the "outage"?  ping more than one device (Host OS/Router/Google etc) just to make sure.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I have built a test machine to build some environments to help my learning of Server and Windows 8. I cannot afford a server class system, and am hoping to get knowledge out of the lower cost workstation class hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to MikeAWood - it was a NIC driver. I had forgotten to update the network card drivers, as Microsoft installed the default ones and I didn't "need" to straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my xRDP connection to the guest VM (Win10 pro host, ubuntu 20.04 guest) would dropout approximately once an hour then spontaneously recover after a minute. I switched the following setting to off: hypervmanager->[guestvm]->hardware->network->hardware acceleration -> VMQ (as recommended here: [dmunified](https://dmunified.com/2016/05/16/hyper-v-vms-losing-network-connectivity-beware-vmq/) ) and my dropouts stopped.